# VS Code Launch Client in Debug Mode when Remote-SSH'ing

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, debugging, vscode-remote-ssh

I am using the Remote SSH plugin to load up a project on an EC2 instance. There is some port forwarding magic that the plugin is taking care of. When I try to launch the client in debug mode VS Code opens a browser with a blank page and about:blank as the address.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fxrmG.png)

I created a launch.json file and went through basic debug steps

Comment: The blank page when launching the client in debug mode is caused by a mismatch between the port that Visual Studio Code is trying to connect to and the port that the client is actually listening on.

Comment: Is there some extra config values, which I am missing in my launch.json file, which would map my debug session to the port running on the remote machine?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The blank page when launching the client in debug mode is caused by a mismatch between the port that Visual Studio Code is trying to connect to and the port that the client is actually listening on.

To fix this, you need to make sure that the port that Visual Studio Code is trying to connect to is the same port that the client is listening on. You can do this by editing the `launch.json` file.

**To edit the `launch.json` file:**

1. Open the `launch.json` file in a text editor.
2. Find the following line:

```
"port": 9229
```

3. Change the port number to the port that the client is listening on. For example, if the client is listening on port 8080, change the line to:

```
"port": 8080
```

4. Save the `launch.json` file.

Once you have edited the `launch.json` file, Visual Studio Code should be able to connect to the client and start debugging.

**Here are some additional troubleshooting tips:**

- Make sure that the client is running before you try to launch it in debug mode.
- Make sure that the port that Visual Studio Code is trying to connect to is open. You can check this by running the following command:

```
netstat -ano | grep 9229
```

If the port is open, you should see a line similar to the following:

```
tcp6       0      0  :::9229     :::*          LISTEN    2002/vscode
```

If the port is not open, you need to open it before you can start debugging. You can open the port by running the following command:

```
sudo ufw allow 9229
```

- If you are still having problems launching the client in debug mode, try restarting Visual Studio Code and the client.

If you are still having problems, please provide more information about your project and the Remote SSH plugin that you are using.

Comment: My apologies for the late reply. Thank you for this answer. I will test this out and let you know if this fixed my issue. It's been 3 months but I have long since given up on VS Code's debugging with the Remote SSH Plugin. I will revisit this and hopefully your solution works. In either case thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks for all the work you did to explain your solution.

Comment: My double apologies for my late reply too.